# stuck at TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and currently learning. It seems that I am stuck dealing with the `undefined` property.

Tried too match the code with the tutorial but nothing happened, am I missing something? sorry for my English btw.

```js
addDishToCourse(courseName,dishName,dishPrice)  {

    const dish = {
        name: dishName,
        price: dishPrice,
    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish); 
},
```

When I tried to call the property of **price** in :

```js
const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price;
```

It shows the error of property of **price** `undefined`.

This is my first ever question, sorry if I put it in the wrong fromat.

** updated
This is my whole code, in case it causes confusion

```js
    const menu = {
        _courses : {
            appetizers: [],
            mains: [],
            desserts: [],
        },
        get appetizers () {
            return this._courses.appetizers;
        },
        get mains () {
            return this._courses.mains;
        },
        get mains () {
            return this._courses.mains;
        },
        get desserts () {
            return this._courses.desserts;
        },
        set appetizers(appetizers) {
            this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
        },
        set mains(mains) {
            this._courses.mains = mains;
        },
        set desserts(desserts) {
            this._courses.desserts = desserts;
        },
        get courses () {
            return {
                appetizers: this.appetizers,
                mains: this.mains,
                desserts:this.desserts,
            };
        },
        addDishToCourse(courseName,dishName,dishPrice) {
            const dish = {
                name: dishName,
                price: dishPrice,
            };
            return this._courses[courseName].push(dish); 
        },
        getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
            const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
            const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
            return dishes[random];
        },
        generateRandomMeal () {
            const appetizers = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
            const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
            const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
            const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price;
            
            return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name},${main.name},${dessert.name}, and the total price is ${totalPrice}`;
        },
    };
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers','fish',5.00);
```

Comment: i assume the price is undefined because i did something wrong with the function of addDishToCourse, so maybe the fault is there

Comment: `it shows the error of property of 'price' undefined.` That is misunderstanding. The error says they can not find price attribute in undefined value. That means they can not find price attribute in `appetizers` or `main` or `desserts`.

Comment: Will you please upload the whole code?

Comment: there, i hope it's readable

Comment: appetizers is an array of dishes where each dish has a price. The appetizer array doesnt have a property called price. You need appetizers.dish.price.
This is if you have access to the menu when you write 
"const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price;"